# Not getting stripePublishableKey in latest version of stripe from Account class

Tags: java, stripe-payments

I am not able to get `secretKey.` and `publishableKey` from created Account. 
It is working with stripe version 5.35.1 , but not working with 10.12.1.

I have changed in pom.xml file too.

I have tried to google but not found any solution.

```
Account account = stripePaymentService.createDifferedAccount(COUNTRY_CODE, user.getEmail());

stripeByEvent.setAccessToken(account.getKeys().getSecret());
stripeByEvent.setStripePublishableKey(account.getKeys().getPublishable());
```

Here , `account.getKeys().getSecret()` is working in stripe version 5.10.X , but it's throwing compile time error in version 10.12.1 .

**pom.xml**:

```
<stripe-java.version>10.12.1</stripe-java.version>
```

Compile-time error: `Can not resolve method 'getKeys()'`

Comment: Please post full error message ([edit] your question and append it there, not in comments). Also did you mean `secretKey` or is `screatKey` correct?

Answer (score 0):

This is expected, the `10.x` release of Stripe's java library is [pinned](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-java/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#1000---2019-05-24) to API version `2019-05-16`. As of `2019-02-19` the `keys` hash on a Connect Account is [no more](https://stripe.com/docs/upgrades#2019-02-19).

> The keys property on Account creation has been removed. Platforms should now authenticate as their connected accounts with their own key via the Stripe-Account header.

You should instead use the `Stripe-Account` header on [requests](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/authentication#stripe-account-header),

```
Stripe.apiKey = "PLATFORM_SECRET_KEY";
RequestOptions requestOptions = RequestOptions.builder().setStripeAccount("CONNECTED_STRIPE_ACCOUNT_ID").build();

Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
params.put("email", "person@example.com");

Customer cus = Customer.create(params, requestOptions);
```

On [the front-end](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/reference) you can use `stripeAccount` property in Stripe.js with your Platform's publishable key to create a Token/Source/PaymentMethod on the Connected Account

```
var stripe = Stripe('PLATFORM_PUB_KEY',{stripeAccount:'CONNECTED_ACCOUNT_ID'});
```